# From which chapter the manga continues after the end of the anime?

Tags: brothers-conflict

I've already watched the anime and now I want to read the manga from the end of the anime.

Can someone please tell me where in the manga does the anime end?

Comment: Actually brothers conflict is based of a novel series,and the manga is written after the animation so it's technically not complete,if you want to read it i suggest you pickup the novel it has 13 volumes in total.